# searchkick requests together with active record requests rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

I have a trouble. For example I have a model Article, and my `search_data` method below

```
def search_data
  title: title,
  body: body
end
```

And I need to receive some records from my controller according to some attributes, for example:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.where(user_id: user_id).search(query)
end
```

But this approach received all data whos according to query in `search` method ignoring `where` method, while I need to search by `search` method among data received by `where` method. How to resolve this?

**Update**

Desirely to use `where` before `search` method, not the inside it

Answer (score 1):

It appears SearchKick doesn't allow you to chain a search onto an ActiveRecord Relation like that. It uses ElasticSearch to search instead of your database so if you did that you would be querying two databases for the information. However, [it does provide a `where` option](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#querying) for the `search` method:

```
Article.search(query, where: {user_id: user_id})
```

If you absolutely have to make the ActiveRecord query first, you could get the IDs from the first query and provide them to the second.

```
ids = Article.where(user_id: user_id)
Article.search(query, where: {id: ids})
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here tis to make sure that every attribute in your where query also exist in your search_data method. Example:

```
Message.search search_term, where: {or: [[{user_id: current_user.id}, {recipient_id: current_user.id}]]}
```

I am looking to find messages with the `search_term` where the current user is either sender or recipient.

Therefore in my search_data method (in `model.rb`) I should have:

```
  def search_data
    {   user_id: user_id,
        recipient_id: recipient_id,
        title: title,
        description: description,
    }
```

And this works well. this is using Searchkick gem.